# Error while running migration in Laravel. The given Closure has no parameters

Tags: php, laravel

Error Details are given below:

```
The given Closure has no parameters.
  at \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ReflectsClosures.php:58
54▕             return [$parameter->getName() => Reflector::getParameterClassNames($parameter)];
55▕         })->filter()->values()->all();
56▕
57▕         if (empty($types)) {
58▕             throw new RuntimeException('The given Closure has no parameters.');
59▕         }
60▕
61▕         if (isset($types[0]) && empty($types[0])) {  
62▕             throw new RuntimeException('The first parameter of the given Closure is missing a type hint.');

  1   E:\Projects\BE-\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler.php:62
      Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler::firstClosureParameterTypes(Object(Closure))
  2   E:\Projects\BE-DEV\api\v2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php:234
      Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler::handles(Object(RuntimeException))
```

This is the migration file. No trace log available. Did research, but couldn't find RCA and solution. Can anyone help to resolve this issue. No migration file is working. This error appears for each migration.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
  
class CreateUserProcedure extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $procedure = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `get_user_from_userid`;
            CREATE PROCEDURE `get_user_from_userid` (IN idx int)
            BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = idx;
            END;";
  
        \DB::unprepared($procedure);
    }
  
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
         
    }
}
```

Comment: Migrations in Laravel don't work that way. Please read more about them here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations

Comment: @DanielL This is a perfectly fine migration to add a procedure to the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons this could happen. A way to debug this would start at the question of why you have no entry in your log file. The logging happens in the exception handler (`app/Exceptions/Handler.php`).

The parent uses the `ReflectsClosures` trait which appears in your error message.

In the register function you would call `$this->reportable` or `$this->renderable` with closures. These closures need to have the Exception/Throwable as a parameter and that parameter needs to be type-hinted (e.g. with `Throwable`).

I would bet this is where your error is. Your migration looks fine to me.